# Is there a simple method to make it as `""` instead of `None` in the template input?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In the template use the `{{ data.user_data.id_card }}` to show the value, but I get the `None` in it:

[image]

Is there a simple method to make it as `""` instead of `None` in the input?

Because I think use the `{% if %}` is too trouble, and not concise in my code.

If there is a template-filter method I can use?

Comment: Are you after: `{{ data.user_data.id_card|default:"" }}` ?

Comment: I tried, there says: namespace 'default' is not bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`default_if_none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) to replace `None` values in template.

```
{{ data.user_data.id_card|default_if_none:"" }}
```

Use [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#default) to replace empty strings in template.

```
{{ data.user_data.id_card|default:"Nothing" }}
```